# Underline in RTF reporting in R

Tags: r, nlp

Hi I want to create following RTF from a data frame in R-

```
df <-

Country         N1   Mean1   SD1   N2   Mean2    SD1 
----------------------------------------------------
Bangladesh      52   25.03   0.02  43   22.31   0.08
Germany         42   95.01   1.02  53   9.31    0.09
Italy            2   20.22   0.00  11   8.09    1.11
---
```

I want the report as:

```
                    Treatment A         Treatment B 
Country          N    Mean    SD     N    Mean     SD 
------------------------------------------------------
Bangladesh      52   25.03   0.02    43   22.31   0.08
Germany         42   95.01   1.02    53   9.31    0.09
Italy            2   20.22   0.00    11   8.09    1.11
---
```

with two underlines under texts "Treatment A" and "Treatment B".
Like-

```
        Treatment A
------------------------
N        Mean         SD
```

Can any one please help me.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  Have a look at `sprintf` and `paste(, sep=..)`

Comment: I want to create RTF. Does sprintf / paste(, sep=..) work in RTF? @ Ricardo Saporta

Comment: why `rtf` as opposed to `txt`?   Either way, use `sprintf` to get your format correct, then use `cat(file = ...)` to output to file

Answer (score 0):

Five years later, there is finally a package that can easily do what you are asking for.  It is called [reporter](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=reporter). It is the only R package I know of that can do reporting in RTF, PDF, and plain text. You can add the spanning headers with the `spanning_header()` function.

Here is an example:

```
library(reporter)
library(magrittr)

# Sample data
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
Country         N1   Mean1   SD1   N2   Mean2    SD2 
Bangladesh      52   25.03   0.02  43   22.31   0.08
Germany         42   95.01   1.02  53   9.31    0.09
Italy            2   20.22   0.00  11   8.09    1.11')

# Create table
tbl <- create_table(df) %>% 
  column_defaults(width = .5) %>% 
  spanning_header(N1, SD1, label = "Treatment A") %>% 
  spanning_header(N2, SD2, label = "Treatment B") %>% 
  define(Country, width = 1) %>% 
  titles("Table 1.0", "Treatments by Country") %>% 
  footnotes("* Country of Site")

# Create report and add table
rpt <- create_report("test.rtf", output_type = "RTF") %>% 
  options_fixed(uchar = "-") %>% 
  add_content(tbl)

# Write out report
write_report(rpt)
```

Here is the output:

```
                    Table 1.0
              Treatments by Country
 
                Treatment A       Treatment B
             ----------------- -----------------
 Country        N1 Mean1   SD1    N2 Mean2   SD2
 -----------------------------------------------
 Bangladesh     52 25.03  0.02    43 22.31  0.08
 Germany        42 95.01  1.02    53  9.31  0.09
 Italy           2 20.22     0    11  8.09  1.11
 
 * Country of Site
```